# How to find the value from with in dates

Tags: sql

here below is my table data,now i want to get the local tax value as on today,how to get the in between date values,i expected output should be 5.5

```
Category    LocalTax    LocalStartDate  LocalEndDate
Frames             5            01-01-2011   31-12-2011
Frames             5.2      01-01-2012  31-12-2012
Frames             5.3          01-01-2013  31-12-2013
Frames             5.5      01-01-2014  14-04-2014
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

With this statement you get the tax valid for the current day

```
select LocalTax
  from YourTaxTable YTT
 where YTT.LocalStartDate <= getdate( )
   and YTT.LocalEndDate > getdate( )
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server , todays date and current time is found using GETDATE() function.
To strip time component from GETDATE() for comparing with dates cast GETDATE() to DATE.

Also your localstart and endadte are in dd-mm-yyyy format so you need to change date value returned from getdate() to same format i.e dd-mm-yyyy for correct comparison.

```
SELECT LocalTax
FROM tableName
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12), CAST(getdate() as DATE), 103) 
      BETWEEN LocalStartDate AND LocalEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for SYSDATE. You might want to adjust it according to date format you are using:

```
SELECT LocalTax
FROM table_name
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN LocalStartDate AND LocalEndDate;
```